# Issues while adding and subscribing new Channel in Parse ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I want when some one login into my app i want to make him subscribe to a unique channel.

I am making channel name with user's email like:

```
userEmail : asd@asd.asd
channelName : asd-asd-asd
```

and here is my code:

```
NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userEmail"];

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@"
                                     withString:@"-"];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."
                                     withString:@"-"];
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:str forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

But its not working when I do so i get this warning in console and the channel never gets added to `Installation` class of Parse

**Console Message**

```
[Error]: invalid type for key user, expected *_User, but got string 
(Code: 111, Version: 1.7.2)
```

Whats the issue with my code. I am unable to recover.

Comment: Will you still get the error after you remove the code snippet you posted?

Comment: The error code gives it away. It's expecting _User but got a string. could be many things, either you started a method before this that you didn't finish, you have incomplete code before this snippet. You placed this in an inappropriate method etc. Who knows. It's clearly thinking you want it to be a _User, I would suggest looking elsewhere as this particular code seems fine. See Error Codes here : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#errors

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because the Array field in the parse do not accept special characters.